# cannot assign void to an implicitly typed local varial Twilio Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, twilio

i want to send a message to mobile device using the twilio api i am using asp.net c# Mvc4, so for that i downloaded the twilio.mvc and twilio library following the tutorial on the website, but now its giving me error whats i the problem is it with the API code or libraries.

```
string AccountSid = "AC45b00a5504e242b8a486ebf4cad405c9";
string AuthToken = "9b192f3af2c286c387772076a5360d89";
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

var message = twilio.SendMessage("+17036394054", "+923437142161", "Hey its a test message from twilio", "", null);
Console.WriteLine(message.Sid); 

responce.StatusCode = 401;

return responce;
```

Comment: What error you are getting? from which line?

Comment: @Anuraj Error is :: Cannot assign void to an implicitly -type local variable

On var message = twilio.Sendmessage

Comment: The only line it could be is where `message` is declared and assigned.. but this does indeed follow the tutorial on their website. I would submit a support ticket to Twilio if `SendMessage` returns `void`.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead so what should i do i mean how i fix this

Comment: I think some other line is causing the problem. Here is an example from Twilio `using System;
using Twilio;
class Example
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "AC32a3c49700934481addd5ce1659f04d2";
    string AuthToken = "";
 
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
    var message = twilio.SendMessage("+14158141829", "+14159352345", "Jenny please?! I love you <3", "");
 
    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
  }
}` Source - [http://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install]

Comment: @user3359326 Click on `SendMessage` and press `F12`. What does it return? `void`?

Comment: @Anuraj No its the var message = twilio.sendmessage line its causing the error twilio.sendmessage returns void i think so

Comment: @SimonWhitehead it returns void

Comment: That's your problem then. `void` means nothing - so don't assign anything (remove `var message = `).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead actually i am wondering why it dosen;t work when we copy the code and run it from our own script while when you press the sen request button in website its request is been gerated aand message is sent

Comment: @user3359326 Different code. They have built against code that has since changed from the version you have. I would suggest installing Twilio from NuGet perhaps to get the latest version.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead i downloaded it from NuGet package

Comment: @user3359326 Then their tutorials are out of date - one or the other. The fact remains that their tutorial expects a return type from `SendMessage`.. whatever version you have returns `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

You're using an overload of SendMessage that accepts an Action and returns void, so there is no return value to assign to the message variable.

You can either change your code to:

```
var message = twilio.SendMessage("+17036394054", "+923437142161", "Hey its a test message from twilio");
Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
```

or this:

```
var message = twilio.SendMessage("+17036394054", "+923437142161", "Hey its a test message from twilio", "", r => r {
    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
});
```

Hope that helps.